# Problem NSTemporaryDirectory Objective-C, missing information?

Tags: objective-c

Our App allows to download some slides from an external server, all it's working well but when two or three days these slides put on black and to fixed we have to resync again all the data.

We used this function to load the slides, I thought that the problem was here because I was checking all the forums and all saying that is better to save this kind of documents on the Library Path, but I tried to do it without success, can you help me:

```
// Building path to untar path and checking if it doesn't exist
NSString* untarDir = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"shows"];
NSString* checkDir = [untarDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:idPresentation];
```

I tried to adapt it with NSLibraryDirectory but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary directory is cleared by system (on their own rules), use instead cache directory (or documents), as below

```
NSString* untarDir = [[[NSFileManager.defaultManager 
    URLForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask 
    appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:NULL]  
    URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"shows"] path];

...
```

Comment: @JaimeJunquera, just replace `NSTemporaryDirectory()` in the same way. You can do this.

Comment: They said that I can't use NSString* a warning, remplacing in the others ones, that I put you in the link

Comment: @JaimeJunquera, if you can use `NSString`, then remove `path` call at the end and work with `NSURL`s.

Comment: All my NSStrings have to chanfe for an URL types?